# Overflow of child div spilling out into parent div

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to solve a number of issues for this questionnaire I'm making. I've reformatted this question because my old one was pretty confusing and I'm taking a new angle on the issue.

With the new code I've summited the problem is that the child div .question-container inside the .questionnaire-box is spilling out all the text past the set height. I prefer .question-container to have the same height as .questionnaire-box and scroll on overflow.

```css
.questionnaire-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .1);
}

.questionnaire-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.question-container {
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.questionnaire-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border-top: 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
 }

button {
  margin 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="questionnaire-container">
    <div class="questionnaire-box">
      <div class="question-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      
      <div class="questionnaire-nav">
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like inside my app.
[image]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

Comment: could you please simplify your question, its currently really complex to understand

Comment: Yeah I understand. I guess the big issue I'm having right now is that the navbar is scrolling with the text. I want it to be positioned at the foot of the container always and then the text to scroll behind it. This is illustrated in the snippet if you use dev tools and make the screen size really small.

I know the question is really confusing and part of the reason is I've hit so many different pitfalls while changing my code to fix it. I'll make a screenshot of how it should look so maybe that can help with the solution.

Comment: I added an image of how the end result will look. So I have a large container that is resized to fit the window of the browser. Inside the large container there is another container that holds the questions and one the holds the navigation. For whatever reason these two containers inside the large contaienr aren't jelling well together.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little overly-complex, but I assume the problem here is that you're unable to scroll down and view all of the content in `.question-container`.

Does this work?

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/bemkkz72/

If so, the critical CSS is the additional `padding-bottom` in this block:

```
.questionnaire-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem 6rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the complicated question I think my brain is fried from working through this all day haha. I understand what you're suggesting but unfortunately, that isn't what I need. The problem is the navbar is scrolling with the hidden information. So it is normally positioned bottom but as soon as the user scrolls the text the nav moves up with it.

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few things I changed in your code for the snippet below - it will be too much to explain everything. Still, some of the most important changes:

- No flexbox
- Fixed element (nav) outside of the DIV above it

Look at the code. I can explain more, if this is what you are after, but not tonight (i.e. "good night" :-)...

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.questionnaire-container {  
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% -50px);
  padding: 5rem 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 100, .1);
}
.questionnaire-box {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.question-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  padding: 3rem 4rem;
}

.questionnaire-nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="questionnaire-container">
    <form class="questionnaire-box">
      <div class="question-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor</p>
        <p>in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor</p>
        <p>in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      
  </div>
<nav class="questionnaire-nav">
        <button>Previous</button>
      </nav>
    </form></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, 

It looks like the footer is at the bottom of the window rather than the container now. Let me look at your code a little more and see if I can fix it. But I do appreciate the help.

Have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these three things in  .questionnaire-nav:

- position to fixed
- width to 75%
- and deleted margin-left: -20px;

Does this work for you?

```css
html, body {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.questionnaire-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5rem 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 100, .1);
}
.questionnaire-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.question-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  padding: 3rem 4rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.questionnaire-nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 75%;
  height: 55px;
  border-top: 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="questionnaire-container">
    <form class="questionnaire-box">
      <div class="question-container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <nav class="questionnaire-nav">
        <button>Previous</button>
      </nav>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you chek this?

Comment: Yeah but the questionnaire nav was already set to fixed, and the negative margin was set to counter the padding of the containing div.

Comment: I'm sorry you were right, it was set to absolute. But if I set the nav to fixed, instead of being positioned in the container it is positioned at the bottom of the browser window... I'm going to reformat my question because it is confusing and I'm trying to address the issue at different angle now...

Comment: I updated my question take a look at it now if you'd like.